# Call JavaScript function present in HTML page from web browser in WPF

Tags: javascript, wpf, google-maps, wpf-controls, browser

I am new to WPF. I am using "WebBroswer" in my wpf application to render a Google map. I have a googlemap.htm page and it contains a initialize(lat, log) JavaScript function. Now I want to call this function from my .xaml.cs file with lat and log parameters.

Googlemap.htm

```
 <script>
        function initialize(lat, log) {
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, log),
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use [`WebBrowser.InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc452443%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:

```
 this.WebBrowser.InvokeScript("initialize", 1, 2);
```

Alternatively you could also rewrite you JavaScript code like this:

```
 function initialize(lat, log) {
    var mapProp = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, log),
       zoom: 5,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
 }

 document.myfunc = initialize; // expose it to the document scope

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So now you can access `myfunc` from C# code:

```
private void WebBrowser_OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic document = WebBrowser.Document;

    document.myfunc(1, 2);
}
```

You could also invoke `myfunc` without `dynamic` keyword:

```
private void WebBrowser_OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{    
   var document = this.WebBrowser.Document;

   document.GetType().InvokeMember("myfunc", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, document, new object[] {1, 2});
}
```

Comment: I am using vs 2008. The dynamic key is not support. Any help.

Comment: I am getting this error Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)). Please help me.

Comment: Make sure that your page loaded correctly without any Internet Explorer warnings. When I tested this code, there was a warning about ActiveX content or something like that.

Comment: Take at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you very munch for you post. I have changed my code and still getting error. I have posted my complete code in the below link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502898/wpf-error-while-calling-javascript-function-unknown-name-exception-from-hr Can you help me.

Comment: Yes, I got the problem. I try to call the JavaScript function without loading the HTML page. So I have first loaded the html page and then called the JavaScript function and its working for me. Thank you very munch for you replay and help.