# Unable to execute a script inside WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am creating a kind of bot to download a dynamically generated CSV file from a website. I was able to reach the form that triggers the download on submit. But unable to submit the form using predefined JavaScript function inside the web-application. Here is my code:

```
object y = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SWESubmitForm", new object[] {"SIPopupIEForm", "s_0", "'s_3_1_50_0'", "''" });
```

Problem is that the `y` is always `null`. I don't know whether the script is being called or not. I tried the function inside Firefox's console like this:

```
SWESubmitForm(document.SIPopupIEForm,s_0,"s_3_1_50_0","")
```

And it's executing correctly. It triggers the download.

Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: When/where do you call `webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript`? Also share the url. Such question needs a scenario or code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am calling it inside a timer. But it is being called only once. I can't share the Url because it will require login to that portal.

Comment: You should call the method in `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: Also probably it will do the trick: `this.webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:SWESubmitForm(document.SIPopupIEForm,s_0,'s_3_1_50_0','');");` Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39268524/3110834).

Comment: Also the first element in the array of parameters in `InvokeScript` which you tried is wrong.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I tried `document.SIPopupIEForm` as the first parameter of `InvokeScript` but it didn't work. Also, I tried your other solution but nothing seem to work.

Comment: If calling `SWESubmitForm(document.SIPopupIEForm,s_0,"s_3_1_50_0","")` from browser console works so calling it from url should work too, make sure you  have not use exactly the same command in console an url.

Comment: @RezaAghaei can you please give me a code example on how to form this in a string in C# and execute in webbrowser control?

Comment: Take a loot at [liked post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39268524/3110834)