# Error when calling Javascript function located in WPF WebBrowser Control from C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496108/wpf-call-javascript-function-present-in-html-page-from-web-browser) solution i tried to call a JavaScript function located in my `WebBrowser` - control. The `.xaml` looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="browser"/>
</Grid>
```

But neither this code

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   browser.NavigateToString("<html><script>function callMe() {alert('Hello');} document.myfunc = callMe;</script><body>Hello World</body></html>");
   dynamic doc = browser.Document;
   doc.myfunc();
}
```

Error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
>   ''mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' does not contain a definition for
>   'myfunc''

nor this Code

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    browser.NavigateToString("<html><script>function callMe() {alert('Hallo');}</script><body>Hello World</body></html>");
    browser.InvokeScript("callMe");
}
```

Error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unknown name. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))'

do work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.NavigateToString("<html><script>function callMe() {alert('Hello');} document.myfunc = callMe;</script><body>Hello World</body></html>");
browser.LoadCompleted += (s,e) => browser.InvokeScript("callMe");
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!